# Delete a group from a collectionview from observableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a `Observablecollection` made up of some certain elements (groups). Each element inside it has another `ObservableCollection` with other elements. I need this to create a `CollectionView` with groups. If I try to delete a group from my collection, I keep seeing it in the `collectionview`. Do I need to update the `collectionView` in some way? If I try to delete a single element within the group, I see the changes, while if I delete the group, in reality the group continues to exist

UPDATE:

```
public class HumorGroup : ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>
        {
            public string Name { get; private set; }

            public HumorGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> icon) : base(icon)
            {
                Name = name;
            }

            public bool isVisibleGroupFooter { get; set; }

        }



public ObservableCollection<HumorGroup> TotHumor { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<HumorGroup>();
```

ADD group:

```
HumorGroup group = new HumorGroup(Mese + " " + hd.Dt.Year.ToString(), new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>());

if (!TotHumor.Contains(group))
{
   TotHumor.Add(group);
}
```

REMOVE group:

```
  HumorGroup hgroup = TotHumor.Where(x => x.Name == month + " " + time.Year.ToString()).First();
    
    TotHumor.Remove(hgroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MyCollection.Where(x => x.Name == "NameGroup").ToList()` to get the group and the foreach the group to remove all the items.

I made a code sample for yoru reference.

Xaml:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    <CollectionView
        
        IsGrouped="true"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Diarys}">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label
                    BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Dt}" />
                    <Label
                        FontAttributes="Italic"
                        Text="{Binding Nota}"
                        VerticalOptions="End" />

                </StackLayout>


            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<DiaryGroup> Diarys { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DiaryGroup>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("A", new List<Diary>
        {
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 24), Nota = "Nota_A" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 25), Nota = "Nota_A" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 26), Nota = "Nota_A" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 27), Nota = "Nota_A" },

        }));

        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("B", new List<Diary>
        {
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 24), Nota = "Nota_B" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 25), Nota = "Nota_B" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 26), Nota = "Nota_B" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 27), Nota = "Nota_B" },

        }));
        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("C", new List<Diary>
        {
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 24), Nota = "Nota_C" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 25), Nota = "Nota_C" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 26), Nota = "Nota_C" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 27), Nota = "Nota_C" },

        }));
        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("D", new List<Diary>
        {


        }));

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Diarys.Where(x => x.Name == "C").ToList())
        {
            Diarys.Remove(item);
        }

    }
}
public class Diary
{
    public DateTime Dt { get; set; }
    public string Nota { get; set; }
}
public class DiaryGroup : List<Diary>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DiaryGroup(string name, List<Diary> diary) : base(diary)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBk8j.jpg

Comment: I have tried with the foreach but it continues to delete only the elements within it, while the group with the title remains

Comment: Have you checked code with my screenshot? Or you could provide more details with the yoru collection.

Comment: I have updated with all the necessary code

Comment: Use the `Name` of group to compare. And then use the `ToList()` to get all the items instead of `First()` which used to get the first item. Foreach the list and remove all of them.

Comment: I have already done as you told me, but the group remains with me

Comment: Could you provide the completed code with xaml, model, viewmodel for me?